# ModernCV Add Name to Footer

Tags: formatting, moderncv, footer

I am using ModernCV, found here: https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en. I am using the "casual" setting which sets your resume to have your name in the top right with your information in the footer (email, linkedin, address, etc).

How do I also add my name in bold to the top of the footer? I have a photo of how I would like it to look here:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KMckdjV.png]

This is how it currently looks:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GU7Edms.png]

(I'm adding the linkedin part later).
The firstname lastname is the missing part that I would like to appear on my moderncv format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting images of your output, it's much more helpful to include a small, compilable document that shows what you've done. In this case, it needn't be your actual CV, but just a basic document using the ModernCV class that people can use.

Comment: So the code in my answer (minus the solution, of course) would have been a good starting point to add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your name to the footer requires changing the internal definition of the footer command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\makeatletter
% This code is from moderncvfooti.sty
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@lastname}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\bfseries\@firstname~\@lastname}% added name to footer
        \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfoot\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Lonnie} % Your first name
\familyname{Andersen} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Gladsaxevej 78, st tv, 2860}{Søborg}
\mobile{+45 31444177}
\email{lonnieandersen82@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/Lonnie} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2009--2013}{Ph.D student}{DTU Wind Energy}{}{Currently finishing thesis}{}
\cventry{2003--2009}{Cand. Scient in Biomedical engineering}{DTU}{}{\textit{GPA -- 8.4}}{}


\end{document}
```

[image: image of modified footer]